# How to handle io.use middleware to capture errors on client?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I need to check authentication for my socket connection and drop one if they failed. My server and client codes looks like the following;

// server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var sio = require('socket.io');
var app = require('express')();

var server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on 3000 port');
});

var io = sio.listen(server);

io.use(function (socket, next) { 
    return next(new Error('Not Authenticated'));
});
```

// client.js

```
var socket = io.connect(window.location.origin);

socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('socket connected')
});
```

My problem is I can't capture `Not Authenticated` error on the client side to handle it and show some popup for example.

Now if `Not Authenticated` error get executed on server side then socket connection still persists but none of `socket.emit('message')` don't any work.

How can I capture this error on client side to make some decision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should catch `error` events clientside:

```
socket.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('The server sent an error', err);
});
```

**2021 update**: for Socket.io v3 and up, errors that get passed to middleware callbacks trigger a `connect_error` event client side, as documented [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#namespace-use-fn).

Comment: You should change the error event with connect_error.                                               
Resouce: https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/

Comment: @Oğuzhan thanks, I updated the answer to reflect those changed :D